# JOIN and the ON clause (NULL values)

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables

```
tableA (id,randomNumber) (2,1),(3,5),(3,2),(6,0),(8,0),...
tableB (id,randomNumber2) (0,2),(1,3),(2,0),(4,2)...
```

Now I'd like to fetch id, randomnumber and randomnumber2 where ID IN (0,1,2,3) from both tables.

So that should return:

```
(2,1), (3,5), (3,2), (0,2), (1,3), (2,0)
```

I tried constructions with JOIN and LEFT JOIN.

The problem is when the ON clause (JOIN tableB b on a.id=b.id) is not true, it returns NULL for the id. But I also need to know the NULL value. For example for tableB it will return (NULL,2) for the first result.

```
(2,1), (3,5), (3,2), (NULL,2), (NULL,3), (2,0)
```

How can I also get the NULL value, should I be using something else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JOIN`s are used when the tables have related data.  Here, the 2 tables have nothing to do with each other.  A better choice would be to use a `UNION`.

```
SELECT id, randomNumber
FROM tableA
WHERE ID IN (0,1,2,3)

UNION ALL

SELECT id, randomNumber2
FROM tableB
WHERE ID IN (0,1,2,3)
```

Or, just use 2 separate queries and combine the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UNION` with a subquery:

```
SELECT id, rn
FROM (
    SELECT Id, randomNumber rn
    FROM tableA
    UNION
    SELECT Id, randomNumber2
    FROM tableB
) t
WHERE id IN (0,1,2,3)
```

You may want to use a `UNION ALL` if you want duplicate values.

Comment: Will this also return randomNumber2 or only id and rn (randomNumber) ?

Comment: @Nicolas -- yes, this will return both randomNumber and randomNumber2 with their corresponding IDs - where ID IN (0,1,2,3) of course.

Comment: I'd suggest not using a subquery here.  It won't use the indexes on the table(s).

Comment: @RocketHazmat -- I would completely agree, but something tells me with that table structure, indexes probably don't exist :)  I up-voted your answer!

Comment: @sgeddes: True.  I don't know his table structure.  I'll give you an upvote too :)